# Smash product to describe multiplication in H-spaces

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $H$ be an $H-$space with a multiplication $H \times H \xrightarrow{{ \circ}} H$.
Someone told me that a multiplication on an H-space is a map $H \wedge H \xrightarrow{} H$ satisfying some properties.  The implication is that the map $H \times H \to H$ factors through $H \wedge H$(up to homotopy).  I don't agree with this:

Suppose it did.  Let $pt$ be the homotopy identity in $H$. Then $H \times {pt} \hookrightarrow H \times H \to H$ would be homotopic to  $H \times pt \to H \times pt \sqcup_{pt \times pt} pt \times H \hookrightarrow H \times H \to H \wedge H \to H$ which is the null map.   But the above map is homotopic to the identity map.  So this description of a multiplication doesn't make sense.  Help!

Comment: maybe, the definition by $H\wedge H$ is just wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that we are taking the smash product with the identity element as the basepoint.

An $H$-space structure on $H$ is still a pointed map $H_+ \wedge H_+ \to H_+$